# AWK - Merge multiple lines in two particular columns into one line?

Tags: printing, awk, merge, printf

Newbie here.. I'm confused how to merge multiple lines in particular columns and print into one row. For example I have this kind of data in .csv file (separated by comma):

```
ID1,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,T,C
ID2,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,G,A
ID3,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,C,G
ID4,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,A,A
```

I plan to select only the 8th and 9th columns per-row, and print them all in one row and separated using whitespace, so that the result will be like this:

```
T C G A C G A A
```

To do that, I tried to use AWK code :

```
awk -F "," '{printf "%s ",$8, "%s ",$9}' FILE > outputfile
```

But it gave result the merge between all in col 8th then all in col 9th:

```
T G C A C A G A
```

Any suggestions are very welcomed.

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
kent$  awk -F, '{t=$8 OFS $9;s=s?s OFS t:t}END{print s}' file 
T C G A C G A A
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it gives result not in a row, but still in two columns and 4 rows.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this `awk`:

```
awk -F "," '{printf "%s %s ", $8,$9}' yourfile
```

Comment: will this leave a trailing space and without the ending newline in output?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it also gives result not in a row, but still in two columns and 4 rows.. :(